# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - AngularJS(including other module)

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting below error in chrome console, when executing the following code -

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
>       at angular.js:38
>       at angular.js:4920
>       at q (angular.js:403)
>       at g (angular.js:4880)
>       at eb (angular.js:4802)
>       at c (angular.js:1914)
>       at Sc (angular.js:1935)
>       at ue (angular.js:1820)
>       at HTMLDocument. (angular.js:33367)
>       at l (jquery.min.js:2)

**appModule.js :**

```
var app = angular.module("app",["psFramework"]);
```

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>PS framework</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="extmodules\psDashboard\psDashboardModule.js"></script>
    <script src="extmodules\psMenu\psMenuModule.js"></script>
    <script src="extmodules\psFramework\psFrameworkModule.js"></script>
    <script src="extmodules\psFramework\psFrameworkController.js"></script>
    <script src="extmodules\psFramework\psFrameworkDirective.js"></script>
<script src="appModule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ps-framework-directive></ps-framework-directive>
</body>

</html>
```

**Is this because of including other module(psFramework) ? in appModule.js**

Comment: Could you share the psFramework module+

Comment: psFramework module : angular.module("psFramework",["psMenu"],["psDashboard"]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the psFramework module, declare the module dependencies in one array

Change this:

```
angular.module("psFramework",["psMenu"],["psDashboard"]);
```

To:

```
angular.module("psFramework",["psMenu","psDashboard"]);
```

Comment: thanks, but I got another error,  
GET http://25.160.7.60:8080/extmodulespsFrameworkpsFrameworktemplate.html 404 (Not Found)
I have mentioned templateUrl : "extmodules\psFramework\psFrameworktemplate.html"

Comment: @SurajNerati make sure the url is correct. The html is not found from the module. If my answer resolves the first issue, please accept.